# Share image from desktop to social

Tags: macos, monitoring, facebook, automator

I'm trying to share an image to social (Facebook mainly) every time I add any image to a defined folder on my Mac.

I've tried [Automator Services for Facebook](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100923055635454)  but it's obsolete and Facebook doesn't accept it anymore.

I've found WappWolf but that's the last option.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know IFTTT but:

-it needs Dropbox Public Folder that's available only in DropBox Pro (or for who registered before 2013)
-it refresh every 15mins and i need something faster.

But at the end **i found a solution**:

SocialFolders: http://socialfolders.me/

that seems to work nice, fast and i can upload 1000pic/month for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Dropbox and IFTTT, this link is to the ifttt recipe https://ifttt.com/recipes/39099-upload-photos-to-facebook-by-putting-them-in-a-dropbox-folder